# How to align with QGIS two layers that have the same projection?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, alignment

I am using QGIS 2.12.0 to create forest maps. I usually succeed to create maps from shapefiles with different projections but for some reason I cannot succeed to align the layer of one shapefile.

As described in the help file and solutions found over the Internet I:

- Assigned a projection using the right-click button
- Assigned a similar projection to the project
- I turned on “on the fly” retroprojection and reloaded the shapefile that I cannot align
- Replaced the projection of the other layer with the one of the shapefile that I cannot align
- Started my map using the shapefile I cannot align
- Erased the .prj and the .qpj files to force QGIS to use the projection I want
- Created a new copy (using the "save as" option) of the shapefile that I cannot align using the projection I want

I obviously check if QGIS accepts the change in projection. In all cases, QGIS accepts the changes.

What else should I do to succeed?

Comment: It looks to me as if you data itself is shifted.

Comment: Could you perhaps share your shapefiles on a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: @Joseph: I unfortunately cannot share these files.

Comment: @Devdatta: Thanks for your input. I requested the original files from the stakeholder. I can create maps using files from this source. The problem arises when I add files from the government.

Comment: Can you instead share the data's extents and what location it represents? Then perhaps someone could identify the coordinate reference system.

Comment: @mkennedy: The area is about 1 million ha near Mistassini Lake (province of Quebec, Canada).
The projections I used were NAD83/MTM zone 8, WGS 84 and NAD83 /Quebec Lambert.
I do not think the problem is related to the coordinate reference system since I can create maps with both NAD83/MTM zone 8 and WGS 84.

Comment: I thought you said you couldn't get this data to overlay with your other data? That usually means there's a problem with the coordinate reference system. Did you try MTQ Lambert? How about Quebec Albers? How about giving a sample coordinate pair? FYI, MTQ Lambert is around 544k,769k approx. center of lake.

Comment: @mkennedy: Thank you for your input. I just tried MTQ Lambert but it doesn't work. I could not find Quebec Albers. I tried NAD83 / Great Lakes and St Lawrence Albers and I get the same problem.

I will try to clarify the context of my question. I have shapefiles from two sources. I can create good maps when I use files from the same source. However, the layers are shifted when I create maps using files from both sources at the same time. Please find below the coordinates of the layers.
Source 1: -264398, 807539
Source 2: 259976, 5577505
Projection: MTQ Lambert

Comment: I finally had to hire an ArcGIS specialist. She told me that the projection of one of my layer was not defined. She hence found the hidden projection and transposed it into Quebec Lambert.

Does anyone know how to perform these steps with QGIS?